# Installing Jenkins by Puppet

Tags: jenkins, vagrant, puppet

I am trying to automate the Jenkins installation on a Vegrant VM . Here is the Puppet file I wrote for this purpose :

```
class jenkins {
  exec {
    'jenkins download':
    command => '/usr/bin/wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_1.565.1_all.deb',
    cwd => '/tmp',
    creates => '/tmp/jenkins_1.565.1_all.deb',
    timeout => 0
  }

  package { 'jenkins install':
#provider => dpkg,
ensure => installed,
source => "/tmp/jenkins_1.565.1_all.deb",
require => [Package['memcached'], Package['openjdk-7-jdk']]
  }



  service {
    'jenkins':
    enable => true,
    ensure => running,
    hasrestart => true,
    hasstatus => true,
    require => Package['jenkins install']
  }
}
```

But I receive error during the process:

```
    err: /Stage[main]/Jenkins/Package[jenkins install]/ensure: change from purged to present              failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install jenkins     install' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: E: Unable to locate package jenkins install
==> default:
```

Anybody can help to eliminate this error?

Comment: Why have you commented the `provider => 'dpkg'` line? It's essential for this approach. Puppet is using `apt-get`, as can be seen in the error message. - Furthermore, why not use Puppet to register the Jenkins `apt` repo, then just install through `apt`?

Comment: I tried with provider => 'dpkg' and without it. Still same error. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Suggestion is still to configure the apt repo for jenkins. But it doesn't seem to make sense. Are you positive that you get **literally the same** error from the `dpkg` provider?

Comment: would you please give the complete solution if it possible. In a way you think it works .

Comment: Just noticed another issue and formulated an answer. Still, please generally provide additional information if you're asked.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that the `package` resource is named `jenkins install`, so Pupet tries to manage a package of that name. This is wrong: The package is named `jenkins`.

You also need to set the provider to `dpkg` so that Puppet will not try and use `apt` to install the package.

```
package {
    'jenkins':
         ensure   => 'installed',
         provider => 'dpkg',
         source   => ...
}
```

Comment: Would you please tell me your idea about my answer above ? I changed the code according to your suggestions and still have problem